# How long would Apple support Swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am in a middle of a big project and we are 60% on the progress.

We are using XCode 7.3.1 with Swift 2.2 for our project and the estimated finished time is in 5 months

How long would Apple support this?

Comment: You should convert your codebase to Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8 (almost the same as 2.2, trivial little adaptations to make).

Answer (score 2):

You can continue to work with XCode 7 and Swift 2.2 for some time (I guess approx. two years). But you won't be able to use iOS 10 or iPhone 7 specific features or whatever Apple announces in the near future.

Therefore, I recommend that you upgrade to XCode 8 and Swift 2.3. It should work with minor changes. The main difference between Swift 2.2 and Swift 2.3 is that it adds the iOS 10 specific features (see [Swift 2.3](https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-3/)).

Comment: Also, a **ton** of changes in the nullability of arguments and return values of Cocoa/Foundation APIs. Most can be solved with the one-click "Fix it" feature, but some escape the radar somehow. Still, tedious work (because of the volume).

Comment: I agree. Apple seems to be still investigating the API regarding which parameters and return values can be null or not and therefore continues to change the nullability attribution.